# How can I fix this error:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range.'

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

I am trying to write a shape detection algorithm using Blobcounter with Aforge.Actually I want to get number of all pixels on the edges of the objects with this code but I could not be successfull about writing clearly and I am getting an error:

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. It must not be a negative value and must be smaller than the size of the collection.

How can I fix that?

This is the code that I wrote:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using AForge.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using AForge.Math.Geometry;
using AForge;
using AForge.Imaging.Filters;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace blobdnm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog sfd = new OpenFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "Image Files|*.bmp|All Files|*.*";
            sfd.InitialDirectory = ".";
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return;
            }

            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = sfd.FileName;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
            BitmapData BmpData1 = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            bmp.UnlockBits(BmpData1);

            Grayscale gfilter = new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);

            Invert ifilter = new Invert();
            BradleyLocalThresholding thfilter = new BradleyLocalThresholding();
            bmp = gfilter.Apply(bmp);
            thfilter.ApplyInPlace(bmp);
            ifilter.ApplyInPlace(bmp);

            BitmapData BmpData2 = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            
            BlobCounterBase blobCounter = new BlobCounter();
            blobCounter.FilterBlobs = true;
            blobCounter.MinWidth = 1;
            blobCounter.MinHeight = 1;
            blobCounter.MaxWidth = 8;
            blobCounter.MaxHeight = 8;


            ColorFiltering colorFilter = new ColorFiltering();

            colorFilter.Red = new IntRange(0, 64);
            colorFilter.Green = new IntRange(0, 64);
            colorFilter.Blue = new IntRange(0, 64);
            colorFilter.FillOutsideRange = false;

            colorFilter.ApplyInPlace(BmpData2);


            blobCounter.ProcessImage(BmpData2);
            bmp.UnlockBits(BmpData2);
            Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();
            SimpleShapeChecker shapeChecker = new SimpleShapeChecker();
            Bitmap bmp3 = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp3);
            Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);     
            Pen brownPen = new Pen(Color.Brown, 2);  
            Pen greenPen = new Pen(Color.Green, 2);   
            Pen bluePen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2);    
             for (int i = 0; i < blobs.Length; i++)
             {
                 List<IntPoint> edgePoints = blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blobs[i]);

                 {
                     List<IntPoint> corners;
                     
                     if (shapeChecker.IsConvexPolygon(edgePoints, out corners))
                     {
                         
                         PolygonSubType subType = shapeChecker.CheckPolygonSubType(corners);

                         Pen pen;

                         if (subType == PolygonSubType.Unknown)
                         {
                             pen = (corners.Count == 4) ? redPen : bluePen;
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             pen = (corners.Count == 4) ? brownPen : greenPen;
                         }

                         g.DrawPolygon(pen, ToPointsArray(corners));
                     }
                 }
             }

             redPen.Dispose();
             greenPen.Dispose();
             bluePen.Dispose();
             brownPen.Dispose();
             g.Dispose();

             Clipboard.SetDataObject(bmp3);
             pictureBox1.Image = bmp3;
         }

         private System.Drawing.Point[] ToPointsArray(List<IntPoint> points)
         {
             System.Drawing.Point[] array = new System.Drawing.Point[points.Count];

             for (int i = 0, n = points.Count; i < n; i++)
             {
                 array[i] = new System.Drawing.Point(points[i].X, points[i].Y);
             }
             return array;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the part that I am getting an error.

```
 if (shapeChecker.IsConvexPolygon(edgePoints, out corners))//This is the part of the code that I am getting an error
                     {
                         
                         PolygonSubType subType = shapeChecker.CheckPolygonSubType(corners);

                         Pen pen;

                         if (subType == PolygonSubType.Unknown)
                         {
                             pen = (corners.Count == 4) ? redPen : bluePen;
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             pen = (corners.Count == 4) ? brownPen : greenPen;
                         }

                         g.DrawPolygon(pen, ToPointsArray(corners));
                     }
                 }
             }
```

Comment: Probably don't use an image in pixel index format. Do you know what that is? If not then it's too soon to be asking a question here because you are expected to do your own research first, as much as is possible. If you haven't searched for the specific term used in the error message then you haven't done that. There may still be a question to ask, but you would need to get more information for yourself first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I know what is the meaning of pixel index format.I am researching image processing for a while but I am stuck about writing code over shape detection and If anybody  have any idea about how I can fix this and explain it to me I would be appreciate it also If somebody know an effective source about shape detection and share in here It would be great.@user18387401